# javascript search - case-insensitive

Tags: javascript, search, case-insensitive

I'm having troubles with getting this code to be case-insensitive. 
This code is found online -  (http://jsfiddle.net/bizamajig/radzq2o2/)

```
 $(function(){
    // Instantiate MixItUp:
    $container = $('.cd-gallery')
    $container.mixItUp();
    $('#filter').keyup(function(){
      var val = $(this).val();
      var state = $container.mixItUp('getState');
      var $filtered = state.$targets.filter(function(index, element){
        return $(this).text().toString().indexOf( val.trim() ) >= 0;
      });

      $container.mixItUp('filter', $filtered);
    });
  });
```

But I can't seem to get this code to be case-insensitive. 
I've tried different things - but nothing worked. Can anyone help me?

I need this code (above) to be case-insensitive.

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried using regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
return $(this).text().toString().indexOf( val.trim() ) >= 0;
```

to

```
return $(this).text().toString().toLowerCase().indexOf( val.trim().toLowerCase() ) >= 0;
```

Notice the use of [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase). We basically convert both the strings being compared to lower case letters before comparing them.

A fork of your fiddle, with the suggested change: http://jsfiddle.net/kykuwppL/

Comment: Omg - thank you so much! I did try the .toLowerCase where you put it the first time - but didn't add it the second time at the end!  Doh. ! THANK YOU!

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem, please consider accepting the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

convert both strings **.toLowerCase()**:
`var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();`
`return $(this).text().toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(val.trim()) >= 0;`

```
$(function(){
    // Instantiate MixItUp:
    $container = $('#projects')
    $container.mixItUp();
    $('#filter').keyup(function(){
      var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      var state = $container.mixItUp('getState');
      var $filtered = state.$targets.filter(function(index, element){
        return $(this).text().toString().toLowerCase().indexOf( val.trim() ) >= 0;
      });

      $container.mixItUp('filter', $filtered);
    });
  });
```